# Where to find Brun's original combinatoric treatment of Brun Sieve?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, analytic-number-theory, riemann-zeta, sieve-theory

I tried to understand Brun's original combinatoric treatment of Brun Sieve.

(Unfortunately, I do not understand German), so I could not read Brun's original paper as in following:

Viggo Brun (1915). "Über das Goldbachsche Gesetz und die Anzahl der Primzahlpaare". Archiv for Mathematik og Naturvidenskab B34 (8).

Many books on Sieve talk about Brun Sieve, but they all seems not follow as much "combinatoric nature" of the original Brun's ideas.

According to Erdos, Brun Sieve is the MOST important elementary number theory method.

Can anyone point a link of introduction to Brun's Sieve which followes Brun's original combinatorial approaches ?

Thank you.

Comment: Halberstam's book *"Sieve methods"* gives a pretty detailed overview of Brun's method.

Comment: @David I'ts not available as research paper but as article in the link mentioned in answer below and then reference is given to research paper. Can you please tell where the original research paper can be found !!  Hope you found it.

Comment: @Jack D'Aurizio I'ts not available as research paper but as article in the linked mentioned in answer below and then reference is given to research paper . Can you please tell where the original research paper can be found !! – DxdxDxdx 18

Answer (score 1):

You can find Brun's paper translated in English (quite a while back) and is paper number 7 [here](http://www.worldscientific.com/worldscibooks/10.1142/5096) 
You can read Brun's paper in Google books (page 99 onwards) [here](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=VAY9nTreXkcC&pg=PR9&source=gbs_selected_pages&cad=3#v=onepage&q&f=false).

Hope it is not too late.

Comment: @MR_BD I'ts not available as research paper but as article and then reference is given to research paper. Can you please tell where the original research paper can be found !!

Comment: I'ts not available as research paper but as article and then reference is given to research paper. Can you please tell where the original research paper can be found !!